# How to retrieve embed image data from Microsoft Graph when there are no attachments?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm using Microsoft Graph to pull email data from a mailbox.  When I get the content, I find embedded images with content like so:

```html
<img id="_x0000_i1029" 
     width="1366" 
     height="672" 
     data-outlook-trace="F:1|T:1" 
     src="cid:image005.png@01D4DE3D.90A3C410" 
     style="width:14.2291in; height:7.0in">
```

When the property `hasAttachments` is true, I look for images that match and replace the content and it works great. The problem is I see embedded image tags like this on messages where `hasAttachments` is false.

Where can I get the image data Graph says the Message has no attachments but there clearly are embedded images?

Note that the image renders in Outlook for the Web with a tag like:

```html
<img data-imagetype="AttachmentByCid"        
     originalsrc="cid:image005.png@01D4DE3D.90A3C410" 
     data-custom="AAMkADY1YjgxM2Y4LTE5NTUtNDBjMy1iZDY0LWIzN..." 
     naturalheight="672" 
     naturalwidth="1366" 
     src="https://attachments.office.net/owa/mailboc@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com/service.svc/s/GetAttachmentThumbnail?id=AAMkADY1YjgxM2Y4LTE5NTUtNDBjMy1iZDY0LWIzN...&amp;thumbnailType=2&amp;owa=outlook.office365.com&amp;scriptVer=2019031102.10&amp;X-OWA-CANARY=kKWSUkiFW0WjlPXXXXXXXXX.&amp;token=eyJhbGciOiJSU...&amp;animation=true" 
     id="_x0000_i1029" 
     data-outlook-trace="F:1|T:1" 
     style="width: 1024.49pt; height: 504pt; cursor: pointer;" 
     crossorigin="use-credentials" >
```

Comment: When `hasAttachments` is false, are the embedded images still sourced to a `cid` or do they show up differently?

Comment: Yes the above example (top) is from a message that had `hasAtttachment = false`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Microsoft Graph API you can get all attachments of a mail:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{id}/attachments
```

or

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages/{id}/attachments
```

When you get all attachments you can check property `isInline` to find embedded images.

You can get attachments even if an email has property `hasAttachments` set to false, because that property is related to not inline attachments.

Comment: wouldn't have though to just try getting attachments from a message that said it didn't have any but low an behold there they are!  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @RiccardoGDev thanks for great reply, but in this case, I need to check attachments for all email by he API, because `hasAttachments` always false for inline, Is ther any way to identify this via GET /message/{id} call?

Comment: I spent HOURS banging my head against a wall. THANK YOU for this